# How to test if a url has basic auth implemented

Tags: ios, django, mongodb, basic-authentication, tastypie

I've implemented basic authentication in `Django` (with `Mongo DB`) and am a newbie in it. I'm trying to consume some web services I had made with it in iOS and android applications. Now, the `Django` backend returns the desired response in Postman (REST client) but not in the iOS app (which handles basic auth requests through authentication challenges and works behind the scenes) so I wish to ensure if the `Django` implementation is correct (so that I shift my focus to iOS side). In iOS, the service returns a `401` `Unauthorized` status and an empty response. Also, the authentication challenges (that are called by the OS automatically) are not received. I had also tried with third party networking libraries which behaved similarly! All this leads me to believe there's something wrong with the `Django` implementation. So how do I verify if a particular web-service (built using not just `Django`) works according to the basic auth protocol? Tips and tricks please.

Here's the authentication code:

```
import base64
from tastypie.authentication import Authentication
from .backend import CustomMongoEngineBackend
class MongoBasicAuthentication(Authentication):
"""
Customizing basic authentication to make it compatible with mongo
"""

def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
    """
    Checks a user's nasic auth credentials against the current Mongo Auth Backend.
    """
    if not request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'):
        return False

    try:
        (auth_type, data) = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION').split()
        if auth_type.lower() != 'basic':
            return False
        user_pass = base64.b64decode(data)
    except:
        return False

    bits = user_pass.split(':', 1)

    if len(bits) != 2:
        return False

    backend = CustomMongoEngineBackend()
    user = backend.authenticate(email=bits[0], password=bits[1])

    if user:
        request.user = user 
    else:
        return False

    return True

def get_identifier(self, request):
    return request.META.get('REMOTE_USER', 'nouser')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see this response header:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="protected-area"
```

Then basic auth is enabled.